# Create specific Json in Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, swift4

I have to deliver some specific JSON to a webserver, but I'm very confused about how to use the correct arrays and dictionaries, so I can't get to my final result. I'm starting from this:

```
["entries": [
              "member" : [
                          "id" : key,
                          "name" : value
                          ],
              "timestamp" : "\(dateString)"
              ]
]
```

in the JSON file I have to send to the server I can only have 1 "entries" and several "member" with specific "id" and "name" and timestamp. I'm aware that I have to use dictionaries but can't get to this result. This is what I tried so fare:

```
var leden = [Int: String]()
var jsonDict = [String: Any]()
var dateString = Date()

for (key, value) in leden{

        jsonDict["\(key)"] = ["member" : [
                                          "id" : key,
                                          "naam" : value
                                          ],
                              "timestamp" : "\(dateString)"
                             ]
    }
    jsonFinaal = ["entries": jsonDict]
```

this is as close as I could get, but good enough because the key in jsonDict should not be there, I added the "entries" in a second dictionary to make this a unique entry.

Anyone who can do beter to help me to the solution?

Comment: Swift4 makes it much easier with the `Encodable` protocol. You can model your data as a struct, declare Encodable conformance and set the `CodingKeys` enum to match the casing used by the destination web server. After that you should be ready to go, using `JSONEncoder().encode(encodable)` - which gives you the Data that you can then add to the `URLRequest`'s `httpBody` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `members` is an **array** of dictionaries, not a dictionary

This creates the structure sorted by the `id` keys

```
let leden = [1 : "Foo", 2: "Bar"]
let sortedKeys = leden.keys.sorted()
let dateString = Date()

var members = [[String:Any]]()
for key in sortedKeys {
    let naam = leden[key]!
    members.append(["member" : ["id" : key, "naam" : naam], "timestamp" : "\(dateString)"])
}
let entries = ["entries": members]

print(entries)
```

And the JSON string with

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: entries)
    let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
    print(json)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Hi Vadian, I think this is spot on, the correct format, I just copy/past your solution to a new playground and it looks very good! next I copy it to my project, I'm not sure about the reason for "leden.keys.sorted", but I will look in the Swift documentation for an answer :-) greetings, Patrick

Comment: It's just a convenience to get a sorted array because the `leden` dictionary is unordered. You can also use your syntax `for (key, value) in leden { members.append(["member" : ["id" : key, "naam" : value], ...` but then you'll get a random order.